# Storing securely passwords for connection to DB in opensource projects

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

Cloud9 is a cool service. IF you create a workspace that is public it will mean that everyone who knows your project url and have an account at cloud9 can browse and download your code. This means that if my project have, for example, connectivity to mongodb, everyone will see login and password to connect to mongo (because it will be in some source file).

The only option I can see to store passwords securely (**except** making project private) is to somehow add them to environment variables, and use **process.env.XXXXXX** call within the code. This seems to be secure because even if others may browse my code they cannot open terminal and check what environment variables I have defined.

So, is there a way to add my custom environment variable(s) to that they would be accessible via **process.env.XXXXXX** inside node's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running project with cloud9 runners there is Environment popup on the right side of the runner toolbar. You can use it to add environment variables the way you want, but make sure to not add a name to the config since configs with name are automatically saved in .c9/project.settings

Another solution is to create a file in the directory not exposed in readOnly mode. e.g

```
echo "password" |  sudo tee /xxx
```

you can even edit `/xxx` file using `vi` inside cloud9 terminal.

But Of course the best solution is to buy premium subscription, and get more private workspaces:)

Comment: using now the first solution while thinking about the last one =)

Answer (score 4):

You can define environment variables in `~/.profile`. Files outside of the workspace directory `/home/ubuntu/workspace` are not accessible for read only users. You can do e.g.

```
$ echo "export SECRET=geheim" >> ~/.profile
```

to define the variable `SECRET` and then use it through `process.env.SECRET` from your application. The runners (from the "run" button) and the terminal will evaluate `~/.profile` and make the environment variable available to your app.

Comment: seems to be a nice addition!

Comment: Thanks for clarification on what's visible, answers a couple questions I had.