# How do the environment variables work within cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, cloud9-ide, env

I want a safe way to store the `username` and `password` of an API without other people seeing it within my cloud9 Ruby on Rails app. Is it safe to save them as environment variables?

I know my c9 code is public but are these variables also public?

How do I access them within the rails console? I tried `ENV["VARIABLE_NAME"]` but this does not seem to work within the console. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Does the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927513/storing-securely-passwords-for-connection-to-db-in-opensource-projects help?

Comment: No, I have seen that answer but it does not make it any clearer on how I use it within the console. I also cannot get it working within my code. (for example my seed.rb file)

I have a feeling these variables only work for stuff you have to start your server for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define environment variables in `~/.profile`. Files outside of the workspace directory `/home/ubuntu/workspace` are not accessible for read only users. You can do e.g.

```
$ echo "export SECRET=geheim" >> ~/.profile
```

to define the variable `SECRET` and then use it through `ENV["SECRET"]` from your application. The runners (from the "run" button) and the terminal will evaluate `~/.profile` and make the environment variable available to your app.

see also [Storing securely passwords for connection to DB in opensource projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927513/storing-securely-passwords-for-connection-to-db-in-opensource-projects)

Comment: Thanks, it works. One important thing to mention is that I have to run the server like you said. Also the password has no quotes which I find strange.

Comment: You can also use the terminal. There the environment variables will also be set.